# Keeping filtered messages in azure service bus topic subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a topic with a single subscription in it. The subscription has a filter that filters a set of UserProperties. Filtering works fine.

The problem is, if a message is checked against the filters of the subscription and it fails to match the rules the message gets deleted. Is there a way to keep the messages in the subscription and not have them removed?

The reason I want this is we have our services configure the rules for subscription when deployed, and a service with a message broker that is sending a new set of messages might get deployed before the service with the subscription client changing the rule set and new business logic. We do not want to lose the messages sent during deployment and process them when the new service is out.

Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you add another sub with the opposite filter?

Comment: Is the message getting deleted or getting deadlettered?

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio I don't want to pollute the topics with unnecessary subscribers if possible.

Comment: @GauravMantri they are getting deleted, no dead letter messages in Service Bus explorer, no indication of dead letter messages on the portal metrics either

Comment: Subscriptions are intended to filter out messages to keep only those that match the criteria. If you need to keep messages different from those you already match, have a different subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, this is by design and for your requirement, you have these options

- Create subscriptions before hand which will persist the filtered messages and your subscriber service could fetch them from the subscription when it comes up.
- Use [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) on a queue instead with one session per subscriber. The requirement here though would be to have your initial deployment send messages with a unique `SessionId` set on these messages (which should essentially be based on the filters you have later now) instead of using filters later